# How to increase the efficiency of loading ndarray with data from an iterator?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an iterator which contains 13,104,640 items of triples `(i,j,value)`. The `i` is index of row while the `j` means index of column of a matrix. I also declare a 2D ndarray with all items are one. When I use for loop to load the 2D ndarray with the items in the iterator, the time consumption is very high.

How can I increase the efficiency of loading the 2D ndarray with the items of that iterator?

Below is the patch of my python3 code:

```py
nn = 5120
prxy_matrix = np.ones((nn, nn), dtype=float)
for i,j,p in iterator_A:
    prxy_matrix[i][j] = p
    prxy_matrix[j][i] = p
```

Can I use some matrix manipulation, such as moving data as some blocks?

Comment: If the iterator was really a (5120,3) array, you could assign all values with one or two array operations, `prxy[arr[:0], arr[:,1]]= arr[:,2]`

Comment: Your iterator happens to have as many items as there are elements in the upper (or lower) triangle. Do they come in any specific order, like (0,1,data0),(0,2,data1),(0,3,data2),...,(1,2,data[nn-1])...?

Comment: `prxy_matrix[i,j] = ...` is the more idiomatic indexing syntax; speed difference may be small.  How slow is `for i,j,p in iterator_A: pass`?  What's taking so long, the iterator itself, or the array assignment?

Comment: @Paul Panzer, Yes! The 13,104,640 is right the number of items in the up-triangle of the matrix where data is loaded into. How sensitive you are about the number! Admiring~ I can make it in spcific order. How to load them then?

Comment: There are many ways of doing this, can you provide some more detail? Where does `iterator_A` come from?

Comment: @PaulPanzer, your answer do increase the efficiency of accessing data from iterator. But after my further testing, I find where the iterator comes from matters. Like @Alexander Cécile said. my iterator comes from `iterator_A = networkx.jaccard_coefficient(G, complete_Graph_edge_list)` and the `G` is a random graph of 5120 nodes and the `complete_Graph_edge_list` is the edge list of any possible combination of two nodes like (u,v). I find the __getitem__() in `graph.py` tasks a lot of time with the pyCharm's running with profile. So my real code takes half hour for a random graph of 5120 nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are generating the full upper and lower triangles and can control the order of elements, the easiest way is `scipy.spatial.distance.squareform`. `squareform` expects the values row by row, the same order you'd get from `itertools.combinations`.

The fastest way to get the data out of the iterator is `np.fromiter`:

```
import numpy as np
from operator import itemgetter
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform
import itertools as it
```

A mock data source:

```
def source(n):
    for i,j in it.combinations(range(n),2):
        yield i,j,(i-j)/2
```

original code:

```
def OP():
    prxy_matrix = np.ones((nn, nn), dtype=float)
    for i,j,p in source(nn):
        prxy_matrix[i][j] = p
        prxy_matrix[j][i] = p
    return prxy_matrix
```

my suggestion:

```
def pp():
    data = np.fromiter(map(itemgetter(2),source(nn)),float,(nn*(nn-1))//2)
    prxy_matrix = squareform(data)
    prxy_matrix.ravel()[::nn+1] = 1
    return prxy_matrix
```

This is already quite a bit faster, but we are wasting time creating and discarding tuples (the coordinates are redundant, so we do not even read them).
As you seem to have control of the generator, consider only yielding the data:

```
def val_only(n):
    for i,j in it.combinations(range(n),2):
        yield (i-j)/2

def pp2():
    data = np.fromiter(val_only(nn),float,(nn*(nn-1))//2)
    prxy_matrix = squareform(data)
    prxy_matrix.ravel()[::nn+1] = 1
    return prxy_matrix
```

A few timings:

```
from timeit import timeit

nn = 1000
print(timeit(OP,number=10))
print(timeit(pp,number=10))
print(timeit(pp2,number=10))
# next three are to give a rough idea how much of the time is due to the iterator alone
print(timeit(lambda:all(source(nn)),number=10))
print(timeit(lambda:sum(val_only(nn)),number=10))
print(timeit(lambda:sum(it.chain.from_iterable(source(nn))),number=10))
```

yields:

```
3.4740988661069423
1.3367053079418838
0.7327171310316771
0.7123838479164988
0.5886694570071995
1.1725806428585202
```

Comment: I find it takes different amount of time when access data from different kind of iterator. Maybe I sould consider replace the `networkx.jaccard_coefficient()` with some operations on the adjacency matrix to increase the efficiency. Many thanks Paul!!